# How to separate not separated input C#

Tags: c#, input, split

The program must *sum* the `even` and `odd` numbers and then *multiply* them.

The problem comes when I enter the numbers like this `12345`.
The array takes the number like `1` element but in order to make my code work it must separate the input when I put it like this `12345`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Lab_Methods
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] number = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();

            int even = 0;
            int odd = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < number.Length; i++)
            {

                if (number[i] % 2 == 0)
                {
                    even = even + number[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    odd = odd + number[i];
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(even * odd);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: instead of splitting on a space you are going to have to iterate on the chars of the string.  maybe using ToCharArray on the string then converting each character to an integer.

Comment: @Darkonekt why do ToCharArray?  string is already an IEnumerable<char>.  You only need to do ToCharArray if you want to create a copy of the original string and amend it.  Also conversion to int is implicit in c# so you don't need to do that either

Comment: @TimRutter agreed.  But since this is a beginner question I wanted to show him a more explicit route.  Plus all chars can be turned into an int which might not be desirable in this case, since only numeric chars are allowed according to what he is trying to accomplish....

Answer (score 2):

If you want to *split* on `' '` (*space*), your input should use *delimiter*: `"1 2 3 4 5"`

```
   // Separated input like "1 2 3 45 6 789"
   // we don't have to materialize into array
   // let's be nice: allow tabulation as well as space,
   //                tolerate leading/trailing and double spaces: "  1   2 3 " 
   var numbers = Console
     .ReadLine() 
     .Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) // let's be nice
     .Select(item => int.Parse(item));

   int even = 0;
   int odd = 0;

   foreach (var number in numbers) {
     if (number % 2 != 0)    
       odd += number;
     else
       even += number;  
   }

   Console.WriteLine(even * odd);
```

If you want to enumerate *digits* within *single number* (e.g. within `"12345"`)

```
   // Single number input like "12345678"
   var numbers = Console
     .ReadLine()  
     .Where(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9') // characters in '0'..'9' range
     .Select(c => c - '0');            // corresponding ints

   // Then as usual

   int even = 0;
   int odd = 0;

   foreach (var number in numbers) {
     if (number % 2 != 0)    
       odd += number;
     else
       even += number;  
   }

   Console.WriteLine(even * odd);
```

Answer (score 1):

This way you will be able to input numbers from 0 to 9 without having to care about the way they are written:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] numbers = Console.ReadLine().Select(x => {
            if(int.TryParse(x.ToString(), out int result))
            {
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }).Where(x => x != -1).ToArray();

        int even = 0;
        int odd = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {

            if (numbers[i] % 2 == 0)
            {
                even = even + numbers[i];
            }
            else
            {
                odd = odd + numbers[i];
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(even * odd);
    }
}
```

---

Input:

```
12345
```

Output:

> 54

---

Input:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Output:

> 54

---

Input:

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

Output:

> 54

---

Input:

```
,1.2 34|5
```

Output:

> 54

---